Laravel and google wallet
I'm currently working on a laravel project, and need to generate a card with a custom qr code on it, for in a google wallet. I'm using this package https://github.com/google-wallet , used their code, to generate a card. Changed some values like the env variable, to get to the right json file.
I also created a google generic card in the wallet dashboard.
I'm getting this error { "error": { "code": 400, "message": "Invalid resource ID: ***", "errors": [ { "message": "Invalid resource ID: ***.test", "domain": "walletobjects", "reason": "invalidResource" } ] } }
A generic card does not seem to have an issuer id. Any idea on how to fix this?

What do you mean by "generate a card"? Are you trying to create a card number for a payment card (e.g. credit or debit card)? What are you trying to use it for? It looks like you might be trying to use it in a request to some kind of web API, which is returning a 400 bad request status - is this the case, and if so, what API are you trying to call?

@sbridewell I'm using the google wallet api itself with the github repository, from my post. I just want to have a button for each user, to create a card for in their wallet which has some text on it and a qr code, sending people that scan the qr code to be redirected to the user it's profile.
